# Releasing ViewModel classes in a WPF Caliburn.micro app

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I wrote a program that has a window with a user control.

The window has a property 'ActiveView' that the user control is bound to.

I have a switch/case statement that sets ActiveView to a view model based on a selected list item.

```
Case "option1":
ActiveView = new OptionOneViewModel();
Break;

Case "option2":
ActiveView = new OptionTwoViewModel();
Break;
```

My question is, Everytime I click an option I am creating a new ViewModel. Say I click option 1, the ViewModel is shown, then I click on option 2 and another ViewModel is created. Is the first ViewModel still a resource or is it automatically disposed and replaced by the new ViewModel.

To save resources should I do something like:

```
If(ActiveView != Null)
{
    ActiveView.Dispose();
        //Or
    ActiveView = null;
}
```

Before setting the new ViewModel with the switch case?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to make this work for me.  In the "SelectedSubject" property I am calling "Selectedchanged();", then in the function "SelectedChanged() I am using a switch case to set the "ActiveSubject" property to the ViewModel associated with the selection.

```
public string SelectedSubject
    {
        get { return _selectedSubject; }
        set {
            _selectedSubject = value;
            Selectedchanged();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedSubject);
        }
    }

public void Selectedchanged()
    {
        switch(SelectedSubject)
        {
            case "User Information":
                ActiveSubject = new UserInformationViewModel();
                break;

            case "Dealer Locations":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpLocationViewModel();
                break;

            case "Schedule Information":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpScheduleViewModel();
                break;

            case "Write Off Information":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpWriteOffViewModel();
                break;

            case "Loading Schedules":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpLoadingScheduleViewModel();
                break;

            case "Working with Repair Orders":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpRepairOrdersViewModel();
                break;

            case "Working with Write Offs":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpWorkingWithWriteOffViewModel();
                break;

            case "Generating Reports":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpGeneratingReportsViewModel();
                break;

            case "Working with Application Data":
                ActiveSubject = new HelpSavingDataViewModel();
                break;

            default:
                ActiveSubject = new PrimaryViewModel();
                break;

        }
    }
```